# Generate core.logic statements using macros

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I'm trying to build up a core.logic statement dynamically by "filling in the blanks". Here's a simple example:

```
(def number 42)
(def stmt `(run* [q] (== q ~number))
(eval stmt)
```

However I get a `clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: user/q, compiling:(null:20:12)`.

I've tried every combination of quoting, unquoting and unquote-splicing, but I can't figure it out. How should I insert the `q`?

(And, taking back a step, is building up statements like this the right way to go?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using syntax-quote, the symbol `q` is quoted as in the current namespace.

Quote it unqualified, but unquote that to not syntax-quote quote itself:

```
(def stmt `(run* [~'q] (== ~'q ~number)))
```

Or generate a symbol

```
(def stmt `(run* [q#] (== q# ~number)))
```

Comment: The `q#` symbol generation seems like the way to go, seeing that it's less confusing to look at than the quote-unquoted `~'q`.

Comment: It also is more hygienic if e. g. number were a form with a different q in it.

Answer (score 0):

If your logic statements are stored as strings, you can use `read-string` to have the Clojure form and then call `eval` on it:

```
(def number 42)
(def stmt-as-str "(run* [q] (== q number))")
(eval (read-string stmt-as-str))
> (42)
```

Or, if it's just a form:

```
(def stmt-as-form '(run* [q] (== q number)))
(eval stmt-as-form)
> (42)
```

Note: `` ` ``, `~` or `~@` are usually used in macro definition.

Comment: `read-string` defeats the purpose of using Clojure data structures. I need the macro-capabilities for unquote-splicing more complex operations inside the `run*` macro.